# Несколько таблиц

Tags: delphi, база-данных

Как при вставке записи в одну таблицу (с автоинкрементом) создать запись в другой таблице с IDparent, равным ID (автоинкременту) первой таблицы? Использую ADOQuery и Access 2007.

Comment: Триггер пропиши в базу данных, который сам будет этим заниматься

Comment: С триггерами не работал, даже не представляю логику работы с ними. Как бы без них обойтись? Пробовал при вставке узнавать ID той записи, кот. только что вставил, не получается.

Comment: Без триггера очень некрасиво, но...
1. Начало транзакции (ADOconnection).
2.Добавление в первую таблицу (только средствами SQL, например с помощью ADOCommand).
3.Определить MAX(ID).
4.Добавление во вторую (только средствами SQL, например с помощью ADOCommand).
5. Конец транзакции.
Пункты 3 и 4 можно выполнить одной командой INSERT.

Comment: __DM.Query_zakaz.SQL.Clear;__  
__DM.Query_zakaz.SQL.Add('INSERT'); // Здесь понятно полноценный код, работающий__
__DM.Query_zakaz.ExecSQL;__

__DM.Query_zakaz.close; // Отсюда начинаю получать ID вставленной записи__
__DM.Query_zakaz.SQL.Clear;__
__DM.Query_zakaz.SQL.Text:='select max(ID) as max_ID from Заказы ';__
__DM.Query_zakaz.Open;__
__ShowMessage(DM.Query_zakaz.Fields[0].AsString);__

Вот пытаюсь получить этот ID. Пишет: __Query_zakaz:Field 'ID' not found.__ Не может он найти это поле. А оно существует! Автоинкркемент оно.

Comment: В таблице `Заказы` точно есть поле с названием `ID`? Может оно по-другому называется?

Comment: Да,да точно. Именно __ID__ и в верхнем регистре.

Comment: Когда Field **'ID' not found**?. T.e, **DM.Query_zakaz.SQL.Text:='select max(ID) as max_ID from Заказы '** и **DM.Query_zakaz.Open;** проходит без ошибки? 

Вообще то я, если модифицирую таблицу не средствами ADO, а SQL, использую ADOCommand и переменную _Recordset. ADOQuery использую, как правило, для вывода.

Comment: Сделал подобие своего проекта. С DBGrid, ADOQuery, DataSet. Всё отлично работает. Мозг сломался. Кажется ощибка возникает при DM.Query_zakaz.Open; Уже не помню, столько вариантов понаделал..., что запутался сам.